# How to remove old images from cache, Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I user the [flutter_cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)  for the cache.

I want to delete the old images from the cache.
If the image is not open or access or cache not accessed,  for 2 weeks then simply remove it from the cache, to decrease the size of the app and remove the useless images from the cache which is no longer needed.

I am building a social media app.

Any solutions ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flutter_cache_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager) to handle the cache life-cycle.

`CachedNetworkImage` also comes with `cacheManager:` parameter.

```dart
  CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
            cacheManager: CustomCacheManager.instance, //-< here
          ),
```

And the manager

```dart
class CustomCacheManager {
  static const key = 'customCacheKey';
  static CacheManager instance = CacheManager(
    Config(
      key,
      stalePeriod: const Duration(days: 14), // two weeks
      // others....
    ),
  );
}
```